# SQL to transform all email addresses in my DB in lowercase

Tags: sql

**how can I transform all email addresses in my DB in lowercase?**

I did an import and all addresses are uppercase and if a user registers again with lowercase the system thinks is another email. So I want to change all the emails to lower to avoid further duplications.

best will be to have a SQL query to do that

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is clearly not a WP-specific question.

Comment: You're looking for MySQL's [`LOWER()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lower) function, I believe.

Comment: Yes, how can i structure the query?

Comment: @vancoder this is clearly a WP specific question. We are taking of a problem on a Wp database. However, thanks for your proactive comment

Comment: @Tommaso no, it's a general mysql question which it doesn't seem like you've put any effort into solving yourself. Perhaps ask on stackoverflow.com or dba.stackexchange.com - this site is for questions regarding WordPress. WordPress uses MySQL but not all MySQL questions are relevant to WordPress. And also, it's a good idea to provide a [minimum complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) when asking coding questions

Comment: It's only WP-specific in that it's assuming the WP schema. Apart from that it's just a SQL question.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably what you want:

```sql
update wp_users set user_email = lower(user_email) where user_email is not null;
```

However I'm surprised you need this: WordPress's default collation is case-insensitive.

Comment: Within the Wordpress environment, the collation does indeed resolve this problem.  It is when you are sync data from your store to your CRM, or to your Accounting that it often becomes an issue.

And it ends up becoming 'our' issue because another programmer did not think that MyName@gmail.com is the same as mYnAME@gmail.com is the same address. upvote 2 years later for the snippet.